# Silly lifecycle: Error compiling front-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have an old delopment which I'm trying to compile the frontend and I'm not able to do it because I've got an error trying to compile it with the script 'dev';

```
npm run dev
```

I've got this error ...

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/josecarlos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/josecarlos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.18.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle basketmetrics3@1.0.0~predev: basketmetrics3@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle basketmetrics3@1.0.0~dev: basketmetrics3@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle basketmetrics3@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle basketmetrics3@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /home/josecarlos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/.bin:/home/josecarlos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
9 verbose lifecycle basketmetrics3@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3
10 silly lifecycle basketmetrics3@1.0.0~dev: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'npm run clean && npm run compile-dev && cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore ./src/client'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle basketmetrics3@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle basketmetrics3@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: basketmetrics3@1.0.0 dev: `npm run clean && npm run compile-dev && cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore ./src/client`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/josecarlos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/josecarlos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
14 verbose pkgid basketmetrics3@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3
16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-163-generic
17 verbose argv "/home/josecarlos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/node" "/home/josecarlos/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.18.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error basketmetrics3@1.0.0 dev: `npm run clean && npm run compile-dev && cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore ./src/client`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the basketmetrics3@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "clean-build": "rm -rf ./build",
    "_comment0": "Script para arrancar webpack como servidor de desarrollo del front-page",
    "dev-webpack": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot --mode development",
    "_comment1": "Scripts para generar el código de front-end de desarrollo y usar el código de desarrollo del servidor",
    "compile-dev": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=development webpack -d --config ./webpack.config.babel.js --progress",
    "dev": "npm run clean && npm run compile-dev && cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore ./src/client",
    "_comment2": "Script para generar el código de producción del front-end",
    "compile": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.babel.js --progress",
    "_comment3": "Script para generar el código de servidor de producción",
    "build-server": "npm run clean-build && NODE_ENV=production babel src -d ./build --ignore ./src/client",
    "_comment4": "Script para arrancar el servidor como si estuvieramos en AWS",
    "aws-start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/server/server.js",
    "test": "jest babel-polyfill ./test",
    "test-mocha": "mocha --recursive --require @babel/register"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "create-react-app": "^1.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "d3": "^7.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.7.1",
    "graphql": "^14.4.2",
    "graphql-disable-introspection": "^1.1.0",
    "helmet": "^3.21.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^1.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.0.7",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.1.2",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^5.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-ga": "^3.1.2",
    "react-multi-language": "^0.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-scroll-top": "^0.2.1",
    "react-simple-tooltip": "^2.6.1",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^3.0.3",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.4",
    "validator": "^13.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jshint": "^2.10.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

And my webpack.config.babel.js file is ...

```
// Import webpack module
import webpack from "webpack";
//Import path module
import path from "path";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import fs from "fs";

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

console.log("devMode: " + process.env.NODE_ENV);


/**
 * Code to get the values of environment variables during compilation time for the front-end
 */
//Get the root path. Our .env files and webpack.config.babel.js files are in the root path
const currentPath = path.join(__dirname);
const basePath = currentPath + "/.env";
// We're concatenating the environment name to our filename to specify the correct env file!
const envPath = basePath + "." + process.env.NODE_ENV;
// Check if the file exists, otherwise fall back to the production .env
const finalPath = fs.existsSync(envPath) ? envPath : basePath;
console.log("webpack.config.babel.js finalPath: " + finalPath);
// Set the path parameter in the dotenv config
const fileEnv = dotenv.config({ path: finalPath }).parsed;
// reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
const envKeys = Object.keys(fileEnv).reduce((prev, next) => {
  prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(fileEnv[next]);
  return prev;
}, {});



module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/client/index.js", //set entry file

/*    entry: {
       index: "./src/client/index.js",
       module1: "./src/client/module-1.js"
   }, */

    // Resolve to output directory and set file
/*     output: {
        path: path.resolve("dist/assets"),
        filename: "js/bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/assets"   //It's mandatory to define this publicPath to get access to the website when we reload pages
                                //or we access to them directly with url's which have directories of second level like 
                                //http://localhost:4000/directory-level-1/directory-level-2
    }, */

    output: {
        path: path.resolve("dist/assets"),
        filename: "js/[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "js/[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/assets"   //It's mandatory to define this publicPath to get access to the website when we reload pages
                                //or we access to them directly with url's which have directories of second level like 
                                //http://localhost:4000/directory-level-1/directory-level-2
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks : {
            chunks: "all",
            minSize: 30000,
            maxSize: 100000,
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/client/index.html",    //where is our template
            filename: "../index.html",              //where we are going to put our index.html inside the output directory
            favicon: "./src/client/img/favicon-96x96.png",
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }            
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/bundle.css",
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }             
        }),
        //With this entry we can get access to the environment variable for front-end
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys),
    ],
    //It help us to detect errors. 
    devtool: "source-map", 
    // Set dev-server configuration
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist', 
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },

    // Add babel-loader to transpile js and jsx files
    module: { 
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[
                    { 
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        query: {
                            presets: [
                                "@babel/preset-react"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                use: [
                    devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
                    "css-loader"],
                test: /\.css$/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "saas-loader", 
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    publicPath: "/assets/images/",
                    outputPath: "./images/"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    publicPath: "/assets/fonts/",   //It's mandatory to get access to the fonts when we reload pages or access directly
                    outputPath: "./fonts/"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

What am I doing wrong? What happend?